Wrap pytest mark with defaults
I've got a test that sometimes fails because the playwright screenshot doesn't match. I added a flaky mark to the test so it runs a few times before failing, which works:
@pytest.mark.flaky(reruns=3, reruns_delay=1, only_rerun="Failed: --> Snapshots DO NOT match!")
def test_foo(page: Page, assert_snapshot):
    assert_snapshot(page.screenshot())

How can I create a custom mark that has these values as default? I've tried adding the following and it fails like the mark isn't there at all:
conftest.py:
def flaky_screenshot():
    return pytest.mark.flaky(
        reruns=3,
        reruns_delay=1,
        only_rerun="Failed: --> Snapshots DO NOT match!"
    )

pytest.ini:
[pytest]
markers =
    flaky_screenshot: mark test to rerun flaky screenshots

test.py:
@pytest.mark.flaky_screenshot()
def test_foo(page: Page, assert_snapshot):
    assert_snapshot(page.screenshot())


mymark = pytest.mark.flaky(reruns=3, reruns_delay=1, only_rerun="Failed: --> Snapshots DO NOT match!") and then use as decorator like @mymark? It's not a custom mark, but it keeps your code DRY.

@Dunes This works, thanks! One benefit of a mark is that I wouldn't need from conftest import flaky_screenshot it in every file but at least this is a lot less repeated code. If you make an answer I'll accept it!

Not a custom mark, but I was able to get a decorator with Dunes's help in the comments.
conftest.py:
flaky_screenshot = pytest.mark.flaky(
  reruns=3,
  reruns_delay=1,
  only_rerun="Failed: --> Snapshots DO NOT match!"
)

And to use it:
from conftest import flaky_screenshot

@flaky_screenshot
def test_foo(page: Page, assert_snapshot):
    assert_snapshot(page.screenshot())

